# replace a backslash with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, backslash

In the form below, if I try to replace backslashes, using .replace(), it results the error :

```
<form>
    <input id="plop" type="text" value="" style="width:500px;">
       <button id="button" type="button" value="" onclick="pouet()">Plop</button>
</form>

<script>
function pouet()
{
    var a1 =$("#plop").val().replace(/\\/g,'/');
    document.write(a1); // added for testing
}
</script>
```

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: pouet

If I try to replace another character (like - or /), it works well.
It seems that the first backslash in \ does not escape the second... I don't understand why.

Do you have any idea on how I can globally replace every backslash in var a1 ? thx

Comment: You realize document.write does exactly what it sounds like, it overwrites the entire document ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to replace them?

Comment: yes of course, it is just for testing. In real, the function send a1 data content to another php page, using ajax

Comment: If I let the backslash, the php script on backend can't use the data (I can not modify this script)

Comment: are you sure it is not just the load order? have you tried putting the script first?

Comment: Put the script first. Before calling `pouet()` in your form.

Comment: I'd suggest using $("button").click(function(){ //do stuff  }); instead of onclick.

Comment: It appears to work fine, even with the script second: http://jsfiddle.net/N4D7L/. The error indicates the the function can't be found, perhaps is not in scope... is it defined inside another function, like a DOM ready handler?

Comment: script first : tested, but not working.

Comment: Problem doesn't appear to be the the regular expression, maybe its something else.

Comment: @GuillaumePierre is it realy written like that 
`<script>
function pouet()
{
    var a1 =$("#plop").val().replace(/\\/g,'/');
    document.write(a1); // added for testing
}
</script>` 
or there is more code inside that script tag?

Comment: @Michael (I'm a beginner in js/jquery) - tried, but no luck <script>$("button").click(function(){  var a1 =$("#plop").val($("#plop").val().replace(/\\/g,'/')); document.write(a1);});</script>

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon The script is much longer, but my page is actually empty but this code, for testing

Comment: Try `/\x5c/g` see if that works.

Comment: @Guillaume Pierre try
$("button").click(function(){ var a1 =$("#plop").val().replace(/\\/g,'/'); $("#plop").val(a1);})

Comment: @GuillaumePierre If the `pouet` (what a nice name!) function is inside an other function like `$(document).ready()` or a closure, the el cant access it.

Comment: @sln ... my page is empty, there is only this code on it. The code is included in a PHP block in the homepage of a Boonex dolphin CMS platform. Maybe there is something inside boonex which block :/

Comment: @Guillaume Pierre - Well, if it blocks the escape `\` character, your in big trouble.

Comment: @Guillaume Pierre - Now try it with `/\\\\/g` see if that works.

Comment: @sln nop, it doesn't :/

Comment: something might be wrongwith boonex, i'm used to pissed off by this script >< but it s ok, I can now send my data to the target script

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var a1 = $("#plop").val().replace(/\\/g,"/");
        $("#plop").val(a1);
        $.post("path/to/php/script", {a1:a1}, function(data) {
            // do something with php return data
        });
    });
});
```

If you're just running some code when the user clicks one button don't even bother writing a custom function.

[Tested and working](http://jsfiddle.net/R8psg).

Comment: I tested it like it comes but the error stay the same. (I have not very well undestand the re-set concept tough)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sln, it works using /\x5c/g instead the actual regex